# How to make specific Stripe session `complete` from code (without UI)

Tags: java, session, stripe-payments, payment

I'm creating some kind of e2e/integration tests for Stripe (for real integration) without any UI (only requests).

Currently I have few steps flow:

1. I execute `/create-checkout-session` endpoint (which creates session by `Session.create(...)`)
2. I take `session.url` returned in step 1 and perform payment with fake credit card provided by stripe (this is manual step I would like to get rid of)
3. Next I execute `/retrieve` endpoint (which retrieves session by `Session.retrieve(id)`)
4. Result -> `Session status is created`.

This is how the code looks like:

```
    @Test
    public void successPaymentFlow() {
        //1.
        var sessionId = this.requestCreateCheckoutSession();

        //2. TODO - perform payment, to make the sessionId status -> complete

        //3.
        var session = this.requestSessionRetrieve(sessionId);

        //4.
        assertThat(session.getStatus()).isEqualTo("complete");
    }
```

I noticed, that I can make the stripe session as `expire` with simple `session.expire()`, so ideally the `session.complete()` is what I'm looking for, but I assume I just can't make it `complete` without payment, so the real question is `How to pay for stripe checkout session through code?`

I noticed that I can create payment method by `PaymentMethod.create(...)` where I can pass all credit card informations, but still I don't know how to connect payment method with session and basically how to execute that payment (something like `Payment.execute(sessionId, paymentMethodId)`).

PS. I was looking through the documentation. It is really detailed and well written, but in the place that interests me... There is only information like `make a payment on the page generated in the session`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be collecting card data to create a `PaymentMethod`, you can connect it with a `PaymentIntent`. In this case, [this scenario](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment-synchronously) seems to suit your needs. Keep in mind that if your integration is directly handling card information, you have to prove annually your business is [PCI compliant](https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide#validating-pci-compliance).

Comment: well, normally it's handled by checkout page, but I want to handle payment inside a code, that's why I'm looking for different approach to fulfill this gap.

Comment: @degath, A payment inside the code is what Stripe calls off-session payments. That is why I've mentioned `PaymentIntent` which has attribute `setup_future_usage`. But you can't completely exclude the customer from the process, if Strong Customer Authentication is required.